# Neo4j Filter Using Count

Tags: filter, neo4j, count, cypher, relationship

I just need to find employees working for more than 1 organization (that has a certain transaction). I was trying to filter with `count` so if there name is listed `>1` or they had `>1 company name` associated with them, but both didn't work, not sure why.

I've included `//` the other ways I've tried it (returns no results).

```
MATCH (employee:Employee)-[Employee:WORKS_AT]->(retailer),(customer:Customer)- 
[transaction:SHOPPED_AT]->(retailer)
WHERE transaction.status = "XYZ"  
WITH employee.name AS `Employee Name`, collect(DISTINCT retailer.name) AS `Retailer Name`, 
count(retailer.name) as cnt
//WHERE cnt >1
WHERE `Retailer Name`>1
RETURN `Employee Name`, `Retailer Name`
```

With below code I've been able to get list that has multiple retailers by some employee's names but still includes others with only one employer (like James). Or I can get every name and retail name on a list, so if I could just take those employee names that are duplicates, appearing more than once that would work, but hasn't.

```
    MATCH (employee:Employee)-[Employee:WORKS_AT]->(retailer),(customer:Customer)- 
    [transaction:SHOPPED_AT]->(retailer)
    WHERE transaction.status = "XYZ"  
    WITH employee.name AS `Employee Name`, collect(DISTINCT retailer.name) AS `Retailer Name`
    RETURN `Employee Name`, `Retailer Name`

   name retailer 
   John  [abc, def]
   James [abc] 
   -OR-
   name retailer
   John abc
   John def
   James abc
(but how to filter for >1)
```

Comment: Could you try getting rid of you rtransaction filtering to see if that gives the right result?  So deleting `(customer:Customer)- 
[transaction:SHOPPED_AT]->(retailer)
WHERE transaction.status = "XYZ"  ` the `WHERE "Retailer Name">1` and add back the `WHERE cnt >1`? Then just check if you get the expected result, so a name and a list of retailer names

Comment: I have this ```MATCH (employee:Employee)-[Employee:WORKS_AT]->(retailer)
                    WITH employee.name AS `Employee Name`, collect(DISTINCT retailer.name) AS `Retailer Name`, count(retailer.name) as cnt WHERE cnt >1 RETURN `Employee Name`, `Retailer Name` ```   That works, but how do I add back in the transaction clause? I tried using it as `AND` in the `WHERE` but it didnt work.

Comment: ```MATCH (employee:Employee)-[Employee:WORKS_AT]->(retailer)
WITH employee.name AS `Employee Name`, collect(DISTINCT retailer.name) AS `Retailer Name`,count(retailer.name) as cnt
WHERE cnt >1
MATCH (employee:Employee)-[Employee:WORKS_AT]->(retailer),(customer:Customer)- 
[transaction:SHOPPED_AT]->(retailer)
WHERE transaction.status = "XYZ"
RETURN DISTINCT`Employee Name`, `Retailer Name` ``` OK I added the whole section back, but it was giving me a long list, then I added `DISTINCT` in the `RETURN` I think that worked, I see a short list now.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an issue with your initial `MATCH` statement, but I cannot say exactly what it is without having access to the data model. Could you try turning it into one match statement instead?

```
MATCH (employee:Employee)-[:WORKS_AT]->(retailer)<-[transaction:SHOPPED_AT]-()
WHERE transaction.status = "XYZ"  
WITH DISTINCT employee.name AS `Employee Name`, collect(DISTINCT retailer.name) AS `Retailer Name`, 
count(retailer.name) as cnt
WHERE cnt > 1
RETURN `Employee Name`, `Retailer Name`
```

This query should work in the way that for each `Employee` you collect all the the retailers they have a `WORKS_AT` relationship to, where the `retailer` has at least one `SHOPPED_AT` transaction with the status `"XYZ"`. You then filter the employees on whether they work at more than one `retailer`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
// Find transcation of the desired type
MATCH (employee:Employee)-[:WORKS_AT]->(retailer)<-[transaction:SHOPPED_AT {status:'XYZ'}]-(:Customer)

// Collect the distinct retailers and filter for collections with > 1 retailer
WITH employee, collect(DISTINCT retailer) AS retailers
WHERE SIZE(retailers) >  1

// Unwind to list of unique retailers (only necessary if you want to return the retailer name)
UNWIND retailers AS retailer
RETURN employee.name,retailer.name
```